# Assign Coefficients of Exponential Series

Tags: series-expansion, coefficients

I want to assign coefficients of `Exp[-5*x]` series into `C[0,0]`, `C[1,0]`, `C[2,0]`, and so on. please help me to code for this output.
Waiting for positive reply, 
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: use `SeriesCoefficient` with a `Do` loop. Do not use `C` because it is a builtin symbol. You can avoid one by one assignment altogether as SeriesCoefficient can give the general $k^{\textrm{th}}$ coefficient.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

`SeriesCoefficient` gives you the coefficient of an arbitrary series expansion. Here's code that will give you a list of the coefficients up to a given value of `seriesorder`:

```
With[{seriesorder = 5},
coefficientlist= Table[
  SeriesCoefficient[
   Series[Exp[-5 x], {x, 0, seriesorder}],
   i],
  {i, 0, seriesorder}];
 ]
```

Write a function that will give you the coefficient of a series expansion:

```
coefficient[functiontobeexpanded_,order_]:=SeriesCoefficient[
Series[functiontobeexpanded, {x, 0,order}],
order]
```

Make sure to write `functiontobeexpanded` as a function of `x` or you need to change the variable in`Series` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

`SeriesCoefficient` internally caches its results, so subsequent calls have minimal overhead.

```
c[n_, 0] := SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-5 \[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], 0, n}]
```

I'm not sure what the second argument to `c` is supposed to represent, nor what center for the series expansion is desired.

Example:

```
c[14, 0]
(* 244140625/3487131648 *)
```